# Filling holes between multiple polygons in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fill, holes

How can I fill holes or gaps between multiple polygons in ArcGIS automatically?

For example, creating polygon number 2 below.

[image]

Comment: Copy to FGDB feature class (if shapefile), build topology, then edit to repair errors. See the documentation for details

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried?

Comment: If you are wanting to combine the black and red polygon into a single polygon so areas 1,2 and 3 are removed and the boundary between the black polygon and red is removed then look at the Merge tool on the Editor tool bar.